# Fragment showing and Activity lifecycle

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I thought that when I call

```
fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), tag);
```

the activity were to PAUSED state by the calling of the onPause() method.
But debugging the project I discovered that no lifecycle method is called.
I was planning the flow to use the onPause() and onResume() methods when I call and dismiss a fragment, but it is confusing me. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Some observations regarding the ***show()*** method:

- It belongs to a **DialogFragment** ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html));
- It is only described by a fragment transaction (does not affect activity into enter onPause() state):

  public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
      mDismissed = false;
      mShownByMe = true;
      FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
      ft.add(this, tag);
      ft.commit();
  }

Detailed information about an **Activity** lifecycle: [link1](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html) and [link2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)